# Why am I conducting electricity when using two laptops?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I've recently started using two laptops, often when I use it, they're both used side by side both plugged into the same extension lead. The Mac has a metal body and the other laptop has a plastic body but some of the paint is scraped off exposing some metal.

While using both laptops my arm was connecting the metal chassis of the Mac with the exposed metal of the Dell. I felt a very slight burning sensation and had to pull my arm away (as if someone was poking a pin into my arm. I wondered why this was happening so I thought let me try this again.  Except this time I touched the Mac and Dell with the tips of my finger. Nothing happened. I tried with my arm and the burning pain was there again. I then tried with the back of my finger (sightly hairy) and I felt the pain again.

So my question is of two parts: 1) Why am I feeling this? and 2) Why is it only when my hair connects with the metal on the second laptop?

Edit: I don't feel the effect where I am touching the Mac, only the Dell. Im hypothesising that in fact I do feel this effect at both contact points however because the contact point on the dell has an extremely small surface area the perceived pain feels a lot more, kind of like pressure.

Comment: To confirm it is an electrical effect, use a voltmeter.  Hardware stores sell them for about twenty dollars in the US (though you can spend more, of course). Check for both DC and AC voltage between the two chassis. Do the charging cables have a ground pin (third prong) at the outlet? Does the cable connecting the charger to the laptop have two wires, like the old “barrel” connectors, or more connections, like a USB charger? Do you get the effect when one or both laptops is running on battery? plugged in, but turned off?

Comment: So I tried a voltmeter, there's no DC or AC voltage, I'm getting readings of around 0.006V which I'm assuming is within margin of error. Both laptops are connected to power and are both grounded, I'm in the UK so all our plugs and sockets have three prongs, live earth and neutral. The Mac is connected using a USB-C cable and the Dell with a barrel connector. When either of them are not connected to power their respected chargers, there's no effect. Plugged in and turned off however still produces the same sensation. PS. Check edit in post

Comment: That's weird and confusing. Since you think the hair connection is important, try attaching a hair to the appropriate voltmeter probe. (There's sentence I never imagined writing.) If you have access to an oscilloscope, you could look for capacitive coupling to some high-frequency noise; some/most "AC" voltmeters mostly look for 50–60 Hz. If you just want the problem to go away, try electrical tape. I agree that you've found an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Oh I have no real issue with it its just very interesting. I even got someone else to confirm it, without mentioning the hair part and they experienced the exact same thing. I did a little test turns out the hair doesn't play a factor unfortunately, touching the laptops on a non hairy part of the back of my hand still has the effect. I wonder if its to do with the (type?) of skin on the palm and back of my hand? puzzling...